# Why negative charge delocalises away from electronegative atoms

Tags: reaction-mechanism, resonance, electronegativity, organic-reduction

In the [mechanism](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Aldehydes_and_Ketones/Reactivity_of_Aldehydes_and_Ketones/Wolff-Kishner_Reduction) for the Wolff-Kishner reduction, after the $\ce{OH-}$ abstracts a proton, the resulting negative charge delocalises away from the nitrogen atom to the carbon, and the subsequent protonation occurs to the carbon.

[image]
[image]

1. Why does the negative charge delocalise away from the more electronegative nitrogen to carbon, for ostensibly a longer time period (for the chances of the proton settling with the carbon to be high)?
2. How does this happen, when the molecule that results from protonation here doesn't have resonance stabilisation, but there *is* resonance if it was on Nitrogen that the proton attached?

A similar question arises in Aldol condensation; why is the carbanion the molecule that moves the reaction forward and not the enolate? Since the enolate has the negative charge on the oxygen, I would have assumed it would be the prevalent species in the reaction mixture.

Comment: Remember that these steps are reversible and not irreversible as shown. The hydrazone anion likely has most of the negative charge on nitrogen. If it gets protonated on nitrogen, the deprotonation starts over again. Only C-protonation leads to the diimide which leads to the W-K product. As to the aldol condensation, how do we know that the oxygen of the enolate doesn't add to another carbonyl group? Such a species does not lead to productive products and is likely reversible. Reaction at carbon leads to a productive pathway --- the aldol condensation.

Comment: @user55119: oh, yeah, the W-K question is meaningless, got it. For aldol condensation, I assume you mean the reaction conditions are tweaked so as not to let these products form. Is that so?

Comment: I don't think you should consider the negative charge as "delocalising away". It doesn't happen like that, once you deprotonate, the negative charge becomes delocalised over the whole pi-system, so that there is some partial negative charge on C and some partial negative charge on N. Now the proton can be attracted to either of those, if it goes to N, it just returns to the original structure, and if it goes to C you get the final structure that you drew.

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti: I get the logic for the Wolff-Kishner case; that it would be the same product either way; that's what I meant by my comment. Could you elaborate on the aldol case?

Comment: On the aldol case too the negative charge is delocalised between the oxygen and alpha-carbon. Different electrophiles prefer different ends. Traditionally this is explained with HSAB theory, where carbon is the soft nucleophile and attacks softer electrophiles whereas the oxygen is hard nucleophile and attacks hard electrophiles. Examples of hard electrophiles include Si in $\ce{Me3SiCl}$, Me in $\ce{Me3O+}$ etc. In those cases the product forms where the oxygen attacks the electrophile

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti: the explanation's great, but it's just that apparently there's [this](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/anie.201007100).

Comment: Yes of course there are problems with each piece of theory that tries to predict a lot of things. You can either deal with each problem case by case, or you can use a rule of thumb which may not work everytime. HSAB is that: it's a rule of thumb, and it's still used in chemistry quite a lot, regardless of what one research paper says.